# pyproject.toml does not recognizing setup.py anymore [building new pypi package]

Tags: pypi, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I created a Python package which I uploaded to PyPI.

I wanted to update it with a newer version.
My project contains a simple `pyproject.toml` file, which refers to a `setup.py` file.

However, none of the dependencies listed in `setup.py` are getting installed.

This was not the case a few weeks ago, and now suddenly I can install dependencies only through `pyproject.toml`.

Did anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: It seems to me like a lot of necessary details are missing. I recommend you provide a complete, standalone [mre]. This will help others help you.